# Update cell protection based on another cell's value

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to track data in a laboratory.

Goal. When the value in cell P3 changes to "yes", then cells Q3:AE3 are locked. However, if "yes" does not appear in cell P3, then cells Q3:AE3 are unlocked.

I need to loop through column P locking/unlocking cells with respect to the row each P value is located.
For example if P36 = "Yes", the Q36:AE36 would become locked.

Edit: This code works with line P3. How can I make this loop through P3:P500?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("P3") = "Yes" Then
        Range("Q3:AE3").Locked = True
    ElseIf Range("P3") = "No" Then
        Range("Q3:AE3").Locked = False
    ElseIf Range("P3") = "" Then
        Range("Q3:AE3").Locked = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't really have anything started. I've tried multiple different types of code that I've come across on other online platforms, but nothing has worked.

Comment: Hi there, what code have you go so far?

Comment: So far I have exactly what was given to me from @Scott Holtzman In the first answer. But i unfortunately still cannot get it to work. I can still select the cells and modify data even after unchecking the box "select locked cells" when protecting the worksheet

Comment: @Michelle, I have been messing with this if loop thing, but i know a bunch of it is wrong. It was my attempt. I added what I have to the question

Answer (score 0):

This will handle any number of values being changed in column P. Provide your password as needed.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'did any cells in column P change
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("P1").EntireColumn) Is Nothing Then
    
        Me.Unprotect "password"
        
        Dim cell As Range
        For Each cell In Intersect(Target, Me.Range("P1").EntireColumn)
        
            Me.Range("Q" & cell.Row & ":AE" & cell.Row).Locked = UCase$(cell.Value) = "YES"
            
        Next
        
        Me.Protect "password"
    
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: ok when I enter this it only protects the worksheet. It doesn't lock or unlock the individual cells. What i need for example is to start out cell P5 would be blank. So Q5:AE5 and unlocked. If Yes is entered into P5, then Q5:AE5 become locked (just those cells in that one row). If no, the the cells in Q5:AE5 remain unlocked. I can't have it protecting the worksheet. Only locking individual cells

Comment: I am still able to edit the cells in Q:AE then P="Yes" with that VBA code

Comment: @DannyPanico - Read up on how locking/protection works and implement it that way. You need to password protect the sheet in order for this to work. Protect the sheet and then only allow editing of unlocked cells. Unlock every cell you want to edit, including Q:AE. Then the code will work.

Comment: Ok that made sense to me so I just tried that. When the sheet was unprotected, I erased all previous values and highlighted columns P:AE and unlocked all of them. I then went and protected the worksheet. I enter yes into P5, but I am still able to edit each cell in the row Q5:AE5. Not sure what I am still doing wrong

Comment: @DannyPanico - make sure you only leave checked the option to select unlocked cells when protecting. Make sure "select locked cells" is *not* checked. Also make sure the code is written in the worksheet object you need to act upon.